# Is there a reason that the primary key is nchar while other fields are nvarchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, database-schema

I am working through an example from MSDN that uses a small database to demonstrate data driven testing, and here is the simple schema:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.LogonInfoTest
   (
   UserId nchar(256) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   Password nvarchar(256) NULL,
   IsValid bit NOT NULL
   )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

My question is: What is the underlying reason for choosing nchar as the datatype of UserId and nvarchar as the datatype of Password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no reason. The primary key should be NVARCHAR(256), as is hard for me to believe that the UserId will *always* be *exactly* 256 chars. Right now this schema is potentially wasting (a lot of) space on disk. Note that with SQL Server 2008 [row-compression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280576.aspx) storage the fixed length column would be stored as a variable length one on disk anyway (trailing spaces are removed), but *only* if row-compression is enabled.

Comment: thanks! if nobody says anything different i'll mark it the answer

Comment: Actually, having a 256 character, double-byte primary key (= 512 byte!) seems like a recipe for disaster.... Imagine how wide and bloated the clustered index and all non-clustered indices on that table will end up being!!

Comment: interesting, still if I put myself in the authors shoes, I can't shake the feeling that he must have thought he had a reason there; it just feels deliberate.  Oh well, I guess it's too small of a detail to dwell on.